# Track number of rows in a #table which the population is in progress

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working in SQL Server 2012 Management studio.

In a SQL query window, an insert into a `#table` is happening. It is expected to insert somewhere around 80 million rows with 3 `INT` columns each.

The query execution is going on.

Is there a way that I can track the no of rows in the `#table`?

Comment: How are you inserting the rows ? Is it possible to monitor that process ?

Comment: The Insertion is occuring to a #table. (Eg: #934), Which is available only in that Query window. As the query is running I can execute any other.

Comment: No, what or which code is inserting the rows into #934 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot run two queries in the same window simultaneously and temp tables are not accessible in other sessions if they are declared with a single #, you should try defining it with a double # in your insert query.

Then you could try querying it using WITH(NOLOCK).

Open a new query window on the same db and try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ##YourTableName WITH(NOLOCK)
```

This will get dirty reads, but i do not think it would be a problem in your case as you would like a rough measure on where your INSERT is.

Comment: I Executed this in a new query window.
But received error 
'Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Invalid object name '#934'.'

Comment: You are using a temp table huh? Just noticed this. Well having one # makes the table accessible only in the current scope, current query editor in your case. If you may alter your insert query use ##Table which will make it accessible in other sessions.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to query the DMVs using the temp table object id.  You can get the local temp table object id from the session that created it using this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table', 'U');
```

Then run the script below in another windows, supplying the object_id value from the above query (-1180342868 in this example):

```
DECLARE @object_id int = -1180342868;
SELECT SUM(rows)
FROM tempdb.sys.partitions
WHERE 
    object_id = @object_id
    AND index_id IN(0,1);
```

Of course, this method assumes you had the foresight to get the temp table object id before running the insert. If the query is currently running, you could run the script below and make an educated guess as to which object might be the temp table being loaded.

```
USE tempdb;
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), SUM(rows)
FROM tempdb.sys.partitions
WHERE 
    index_id IN(0,1)
    AND OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'IsUserTable') = 1
GROUP BY 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id);
```

Be aware that this might not be a reliable way to track the load progress.  Much depends on the query plan particulars.  It could be that the costly operators are earlier in the plan and the actual insert won't occur until the last minute.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to run the query to count rows in another window or outside the scope where the table was declared, please use a global temp table.

For Example,

```
CREATE TABLE ##table(
a int,
b int,
c int)
```

And the in another window you can run, this will work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ##table WITH (NOLOCK)
```